# When can I reapply for US Citizenship after denial?

Tags: united-states, immigration, naturalization

I moved to another state and then applied for US citizenship without waiting 3 months residence restriction (I am permanent resident for more than 5 years). For the reason that I filed before 3 months, my application was denied after fingerprints and passing the interview/test.

When can I re-apply for the citizenship, there is no date mentioned on the letter received.

Comment: Had you satisfied the 5 year requirement plus the 3 month requirement in your previous state?

Comment: Yes, I have been permanent resident for more than 5 years.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Expatriates.SE

Answer (score 3):

> When can I re-apply for the citizenship, there is no date mentioned on the letter received.

You can reapply as soon as you meet the criteria.  If you don't move again to another state or USCIS district, and if you don't spend so much time outside the US that you fail to meet the physical presence requirement, then you can reapply on the three-month anniversary of your move to your current place of residence.

The criteria are available at USCIS's [Naturalization Information](https://www.uscis.gov/citizenship/educators/naturalization-information) page:

> Naturalization Eligibility Requirements
>
> Before an individual applies for naturalization, he or she must meet a few requirements. Depending on the individual’s situation, there are different requirements that may apply. General requirements for naturalization are below.
>
> - Be at least 18 years old at the time of filing Form N-400, Application for Naturalization.
> - Be a permanent resident (have a “Green Card”) for at least 5 years.
> - Show that you have lived for at least 3 months in the state or USCIS district where you apply.
> - Demonstrate continuous residence in the United States for at least 5 years immediately preceding the date of filing Form N-400.
> - Show that you have been physically present in the United States for at least 30 months out of the 5 years immediately preceding the date of filing Form N-400.
> - Be able to read, write, and speak basic English.
> - Have a basic understanding of U.S. history and government (civics).
> - Be a person of good moral character.
> - Demonstrate an attachment to the principles and ideals of the U.S. Constitution.

Comment: They just want to have your case handled in one office and yes you can file right after you meet the requirements.